# discord.js Как менять статус бота каждые 5 сек

Tags: javascript, бот, discord

Хочу чтобы менялся статус бота с интервалом в  5 секунд
то есть, сначала, смотрит, потом играет, потом слушает.

Пытался сделать что-то по типу этого. Не получилось. Вот пример снизу!

```
setInterval(()=>{    {client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: ` /help `, type: 'LISTENING'} })}; }, 2500)      
    }  
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var timer = bot.setInterval(function () {    
    var gamePresence = ["Статус", "Статус"];//каждое слово через запятую - отдельный статус
    bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: gamePresence[i%gamePresence.length], type: 1, url: "https://www.twitch.tv/akkulalife" } });
    i++;
},5000)//время
```

Пользуйся братик)

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает! Красава!